# Update custom fields on hook_user_login

Tags: testing

I have implemented hook_user_login(&$edit, $account) and some of custom fields from $account should be updated. I am doing this with user_save(). These changes are not visible in Simpletest. I have tried user_load() in Simpletest before login and after, no changes. The Values are being saved to the db but are not visible in Simpletest. Any Idea?

Comment: Did you try doing this with rules [ https://www.drupal.org/project/rules ] ?

Comment: yes, and it works but i dont want to use rules. My goal is to implement this with my custom module alone so I can Simpletest it properly.

Comment: In this case Simpletest works only if I create user with $this->drupalCreateUser(). It is then possible to assert my changed fields. On user created in my custom module, assertions fails

Comment: I do not know simpletest, sorry

Comment: I have achieved my goal, how can i close this question?

Comment: Please add an answer with the solution for the community ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpletest assertions are working on user created in Simpletest with $this->drupalCreateUser().